# Apply GZip compression to a stream used by a method that pulls data

Tags: c#, stream, compression, gzip

**Prerequisites**

I have a stream `rawStream` and a method which takes a stream and reads it to the end, let's say something like this:

```
Task UploadFile(Stream stream) { ... }
```

Currently this method is successfully being used like this:

```
await UploadFile(rawStream);
```

**What I want to do**

Now I need to apply GZip compression to that stream. I wish I could write something like this:

```
using (var compressedStream = new GZipStream(rawStream, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
{
    await UploadFile(compressedStream);
}
```

But this doesn't work because the `stream` parameter of `GZipStream` is an output stream, so it's the wrong way round.

**Question**

How can I wrap my original stream in a compressing stream and still let my consuming function pull the data out of the stream?

---

**Note**

The above example is actually simplyfied, because I also need to apply base64 encoding. So what I actually want is something like this:

```
using (var compressedStream = new GZipStream(rawStream, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
using (var encodedStream = new CryptoStream(compressedStream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    await UploadFile(encodedStream);
}
```

But I guess if someone can explain to me how it works for the compression part, I can figure out how to implement the entire chain.

Comment: Have you looked into BouncyCastle.Crypto ?

Comment: I've heard about BouncyCastle in some other context, but I've never used it - mainly because the documentation does not make it very easy to get started. Judging from a look at their feature list (https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) they don't seem to support GZip or Base64 - or do they?

Comment: Ahh yes! the documentation ... Better look at the examples, I was just doing some PGP: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/test/src/openpgp/examples/PbeFileProcessor.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the approaches presented so far really convinced me. So I went ahead and wrote the following customize stream which allows pulling the GZipped and Base64 encoded data out of the stream.

I did some tests and it seems to work fine.

I think this pattern can be useful in other contexts as well for turning a "push pipeline" into a "pull pipeline".

```
public sealed class GzipBase64Stream : Stream
{

    #region constructor / cleanup

    public GzipBase64Stream(Stream inputStream)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream = inputStream;
            ToBase64Transform = new ToBase64Transform();
            OutputStream = new MemoryStream();
            Base64Stream = new CryptoStream(OutputStream, ToBase64Transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            GzipStream = new GZipStream(Base64Stream, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            Cleanup();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void Cleanup()
    {
        GzipStream?.Dispose();
        Base64Stream?.Dispose();
        OutputStream?.Dispose();
        ToBase64Transform?.Dispose();
        InputStream?.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region private variables

    private bool EndOfInputStreamReached = false;

    private readonly Stream InputStream;
    private readonly ToBase64Transform ToBase64Transform;
    private readonly MemoryStream OutputStream;
    private readonly CryptoStream Base64Stream;
    private readonly GZipStream GzipStream;

    #endregion

    #region stream overrides

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanSeek => false;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override long Length => 0;

    public override long Position { get => throw new NotSupportedException(); set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }

    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void Flush() => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {

        while ((OutputStream.Position >= OutputStream.Length) && !EndOfInputStreamReached)
        {
            // No unread data available in the output buffer
            // -> release memory of output buffer and read new data from the source and feed through the pipeline
            OutputStream.SetLength(0);
            var inputBuffer = new byte[1024];
            var readCount = InputStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
            if (readCount == 0)
            {
                EndOfInputStreamReached = true;
                GzipStream.Flush();
                GzipStream.Dispose(); // because Flush() does not actually flush...
            }
            else
            {

                GzipStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, readCount);
            }
            OutputStream.Position = 0;
        }

        return OutputStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing)
            Cleanup();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: [GZipStream.Flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush.aspx) may not behave the way you expect: "The current implementation of this method does not flush the internal buffer. The internal buffer is flushed when the object is disposed."

Comment: Thanks for your hint! My unit tests did not show any problems with just using Flush(), but to be on the safe side I now make a call to Dispose() too (and when creating the GZipStream I make sure the Base64 stream won't be disposed with it).

Comment: @RobertHegner unless you object I'll try and copy this code and generalize it in a NuGet package. This will enable a general purpose `StreamInverter` that can invert the direction of ingoing and outgoing `Stream`, which from time to time is a rather annoying problem.

Comment: I'm quite certain that the output stream position should reach the output stream length. Otherwise it might miss a byte (so the expression in the `while` loop should be `OutputStream.Position >= OutputStream.Length && !EndOfInputStreamReached`). I've tried making an edit for it.

Answer (score -1):

You need a third stream for the `GZipStream` to write to:

```
private static async Task<MemoryStream> CompressStream(Stream inputStream)
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    Console.WriteLine(inputStream.Length);
    using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionLevel.Fastest, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        await inputStream.CopyToAsync(gzipStream);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(outputStream.Length);
    return outputStream;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it first compresses the entire inputStream and only when this is done I can start reading the outputStream. So I need to keep the entire compressed data in memory. I need to handle really large amounts of data so for scalability reasons this is not an option.

Comment: You have to [wait until the `GZipStream` is closed](https://www.brainarama.com/thought/6757eca0-910c-11e7-9709-215c776829a5/-NET-GZipStream-must-be-closed-or-it-produces-corrupt-data) to use the compressed output.